# Why was this basic Java question so ill-received?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, specific-question, asking-questions

I passed by a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346832/what-does-next-do-in-java) on Java's `Scanner.next()` method and I was kinda shock that in just 5 minutes, the question and every answer for it got down-voted several times, even correct answers.

So I wonder, are we supposed to avoid this kind of questions? I read at the help center what kind of questions should be asked, but apparently, beginner programming questions are legal, since it's not specific on how hard the question needs to be.

Comment: It probably got downvoted because these types of questions tend to be very 'RTFM'.

Comment: ... and the answers were likely downvoted because they enable that kind of behaviour.

Comment: I guess I can understand the punitive rationale for downvoting answers on very low-quality questions, but I think a better solution is just [vote] to delete the question. That way, correct answers don't have to be downvoted, and the people who posted them still do not gain reputation for answering crap.

Comment: @CodyGray Users under 20k rep can't vote to delete it.

Comment: I edited your question in an attempt to salvage it, but there's only so much you can do for poorly-researched questions.

Comment: That question is now deleted so I can't see what the poster was even talking about.  Is there any way to see a question that has been deleted due to moderation?  Would the history be in the data dumps?

Answer (score 21):

### You can ask about basic programming in Stack Overflow.

It's perfectly fine to ask about basic conceptual issues in programming, about how to structure your code and all sorts of code issues.

### This question got downvoted because it was poorly researched and written.

Questions like "What does the method `foo` do" for a very common `foo` are bad because:

- **There is no real problem being solved or the issue is not specific enough.**

  In this case, the asker could have found out what it does by doing `System.out.println(word)`. Had the question been, "How do I get the next token from a scanner?" or "How do I print the first character in a string?" (assuming those are not dupes), it would have been better accepted.
- ***Any* research would have helped the asker.**

  While I'm not a Java fan, it's hard to deny the quality of its documentation. Googling "Java Scanner Next API documentation" would have easily landed the asker on a good help page. Had the question being about a more obscure API, it would have been better accepted. The fact that it's such a common, well-documented API is telling.

To illustrate:

- [The duplicate of the asker's **problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201191/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-letter-from-a-string-in-java-returned-as) has 4 upvotes.
- [A similar question about the same **problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163785/how-do-you-get-the-last-character-of-a-string) has 27 upvotes.
- [An actual specific question about the same API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071965/using-scanner-next-to-get-text-input) has 4 upvotes.

So it's really all about writing a well-researched, specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - quick off topic question - Since when are titles ended with a dot @CodyGray it doesn't look that way in news websites I've checked. Example: first front page article on CNN http://edition.cnn.com/2014/08/17/world/meast/iraq-crisis/index.html?hpt=hp_t1

Comment: Oh, they're not normally, I guess. I just read those as complete sentences, so they looked like they needed a period. I thought you were using the headings for emphasis rather than titles. They work either way.

Comment: Thank you guys, now it makes sense.